# How to fix a "runtime error" that doesn't affect performance?

Tags: c++, runtime, runtime-error

Submitted a problem to an online judging platform. Code works perfectly with the provided samples, but judge outputs "runtime error", nothing more.

Code is supposed to calculate resulting fractions from inputs

Sample inputs:

27 12

2460000 98400

3 4000

Line containing 0 0 will follow the last input. First number is the numerator, second is the denominator.

Current code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int num[500], den[500], ent[500];
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        num[i] = 0;
        den[i] = 0;
        ent[i] = 0;
    }
    int i=1;
    num[0]=1; den[0]=1;
    while((num[i-1]!=0)&&(den[i-1]!=0)){
        cin >> num[i] >> den[i];
        i++;
    } i--;

    for(int j=1; j<i; j++){
        ent[j]=num[j]/den[j];
        num[j]=num[j]%den[j];
    }

    for(int j=1; j<i; j++){
        cout << ent[j] << " " << num[j] << " / " << den[j] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if you are going to have a max of 500 fractions?  If there could be more then that will definitely be a problem since your arrays are sized to be 500.  Also I  would change your reading loop to be `do { cin >> num[i] >> den[i]; i++; } while((num[i]!=0)&&(den[i]!=0);`

Comment: By the way, the expression "runtime error which does not affect performance" sounds weird. It sounds like "Yes, my program crashes -- but look how fast it is!".

Comment: Is there a need to store the fractions?  For example, can you read one fraction input, then process, then output?  This would eliminate the need to store the fractions.  Your `ent` and `num` values can be calculated and printed on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that the input they give you has more than 499 lines causing your program to run off the end of its hardcoded arrays.

Have you considered `std::vector` or an approach that doesn't cache *all* the input before processing?